# How to transfer type from variadic parameters into a different shape in the return?

Tags: typescript

I'm building a combinations function that produces a cartesian product of input lists. As a quirk I want to support enums as potential lists. I may expand this later to support actual Sets too.

I have code that definitely works:

```js
type EnumOrArray = { [key: string]: any; } | any[];

export function cartesian(...inputs: EnumOrArray[]): any[][] {
  const itemGroups: any[][] = inputs.map(input => {
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
      return input; // Directly return if input is an array
    } else {
      // Only work with the enum's keys (names), then convert them to their numeric values
      const originalKeys = Object.keys(input).filter(key => isNaN(Number(key)));
      return originalKeys.map(key => input[key]);
    }
  });

  // Recursive function to generate combinations (remains unchanged)
  function generateCartesianProduct(groups: any[][], prefix: any[] = []): any[][] {
    if (!groups.length) return [prefix];
    const firstGroup = groups[0];
    const restGroups = groups.slice(1);

    let result: any[][] = [];

    firstGroup.forEach(item => {
      result = result.concat(generateCartesianProduct(restGroups, [...prefix, item]));
    });

    return result;
  }

  return generateCartesianProduct(itemGroups);
}
```

...But this is a type firewall and simply produces output of type any[][], which is not satisfactory.

For example, if I use this:

```js
  enum Color {
    Red = 'red',
    Green = 'green',
    Blue = 'blue'
  }
  enum Size {
    Small = 1,
    Medium = 10,
    Large = 100
  }
  const numbers = [1, 2];
  const combos = cartesian(Color, numbers, Size);
```

it yields the right value:

```
[
  [ 'red', 1, 1 ],     [ 'red', 1, 10 ],
  [ 'red', 1, 100 ],   [ 'red', 2, 1 ],
  [ 'red', 2, 10 ],    [ 'red', 2, 100 ],
  [ 'green', 1, 1 ],   [ 'green', 1, 10 ],
  [ 'green', 1, 100 ], [ 'green', 2, 1 ],
  [ 'green', 2, 10 ],  [ 'green', 2, 100 ],
  [ 'blue', 1, 1 ],    [ 'blue', 1, 10 ],
  [ 'blue', 1, 100 ],  [ 'blue', 2, 1 ],
  [ 'blue', 2, 10 ],   [ 'blue', 2, 100 ]
]
```

But I want it to have type `[Color, number, Size][]`, not `any[][]`.

I think the answer is to do something clever with a variadic generic type but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQjaAN) meet your needs? Note that we need to do funky things to reproduce the "ignore numeric keys" part for enums. If it meets your needs I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz wow it looks like you did it! I'm digging into it.. this `ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement` is a master class in typescript wizardry. I'm starting to see the light for making type utils, but am still a noob. Please submit as an answer... Thank you!

Comment: I also can't believe `{ [I in keyof T]: ...` construction is viable for manipulating an array!

Comment: I have gone ahead quite a bit based on your contribution @jcalz, but could you help me out with the thing i'm "stuck" on now? https://tsplay.dev/mMLkzN (You can see in the d.ts output tab the crazy type of `combos2`.)

Comment: Sweet, never mind. I solved that too, by adding `readonly` prior to the `(infer U)[]` bit in `ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement` and `ConvertArrayToElementAndEnumToKey`. I have enough to post a definitive answer now.

Comment:  I just woke up. Am I to understand that you used my suggestion to proceed past the question as asked, then posted your own answer without explanation or attribution? Is it worthwhile for me to post my own answer here to the question as asked above with an explanation for how it works? Or do you want to leave things like this?

Comment: totally, i will accept your answer if you provide one! I really post self answers as notes to myself more than anything. so even if it ends up being closer to what i use in the end i'll accept others just to give them more points. 

I also realized if I'm generating cartesian products, doing them with an assembly/generative based approach is really dumb and I will be generating instances of combinations with an analytical approach in the real code. But, all these type shenanigans will be valuable to apply to that implementation as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I'll assume that the implementation of `cartesian` is already done and that you're just looking for the typings for the call signature. The compiler won't really be able to verify that the implementation actually matches the call signature, so inside the function you'll probably need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) or something like them to avoid compiler errors.

---

The approach I'd take here is to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` of the `inputs` array, and then have the function return an array of a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) that converts each element of `T` into the corresponding output type:

```
declare function cartesian<T extends EnumOrArray[]>(...inputs: T):
  { [I in keyof T]: ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T[I]> }[];
```

So if `inputs` is of type `[A, B, C]`, then the return type will be `[ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<A>, ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<B>, ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<C>][]`.  So now we need to define `ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement`.

---

The goal of `ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T>` is that `T` should be some subtype of `EnumOrArray`.  If `T` is an array of type `U[]` then we want `U`. Otherwise `T` is of type `{[k: string]: any}`. Naively I would say that you want `T[keyof T]`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the property value types of `T`. *But* the tricky bit here is that in your code you apparently suppress any numeric keys, to avoid the [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) for numeric enums.  So we need to actually probe `T` for numeric keys and suppress them as well.  Instead of `T[keyof T]` we'll have `X[keyof T]` where `X` is like `T` except there's no property contribution from numeric keys:

```
type ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T extends EnumOrArray> =
  T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
  { [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? never : T[K] }[keyof T]
```

Here we're using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to distinguish between `T` being an array and `T` being some other object.  I used [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to extract out the array element type `U` (although `T[number]` would have also worked).  For non-arrays we have another [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to check for numeric keys `K` and suppress their property type (by mapping it to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) which disappears in unions).

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
enum Color {
  Red = 'red',
  Green = 'green',
  Blue = 'blue'
}

enum Size {
  Small = 1,
  Medium = 10,
  Large = 100
}
const numbers = [1, 2];
const combos = cartesian(Color, numbers, Size);
//    ^? const combos: [Color, number, Size][]
```

Looks good. That's the output type you wanted.  Just to be clear, here's what you get with `ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement` with each element of `inputs`:

```
type ColorOutput = ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<typeof Color>
// type ColorOutput = Color
type NumbersOutput = ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<typeof numbers>
// type NumbersOutput = number
type SizeOutput = ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<typeof Size>
// type SizeOutput = Size
```

So it turns arrays into their element types, and enums into their enum type, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-o-M3IW2YZ3pyM3Wm+3IB0O56GF9W7iT91PlJmIIvL8vgbo1+DjK3oR37F3qnfD8fp2lOV7wvWsgPlIA)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer. It does everything I asked for and more. It also handles tuple types (e.g. `['a', 'b'] as const` types).

```js
type EnumOrArray = { [key: string]: any; } | any[];

type ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T extends EnumOrArray> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U :
{ [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? never : T[K] }[keyof T]

type ConvertArrayToElementAndEnumToKey<T extends EnumOrArray> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U :
// in here we can't just use keyof T in order to eliminate the number keys.
{ [K in keyof T]: K extends number ? never : K }[keyof T]

function enum_to_values<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(e: T): ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T>[] {
  return Object.keys(e).filter(k => isNaN(Number(k))).map(k => e[k]) as any;
}
function enum_to_keys<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(e: T): ConvertArrayToElementAndEnumToKey<T>[] {
  return Object.keys(e).filter(k => isNaN(Number(k))) as any;
}

// Recursive function to generate combinations (remains unchanged)
function generateCartesianProduct(groups: any[][], prefix: any[] = []): any[][] {
  if (!groups.length) return [prefix];
  const firstGroup = groups[0];
  const restGroups = groups.slice(1);
  return firstGroup.flatMap(item => generateCartesianProduct(restGroups, [...prefix, item]));
}

export const cartesian = <T extends EnumOrArray[]>(...inputs: T): { [I in keyof T]: ConvertArrayToElementAndEnumToKey<T[I]> }[] => generateCartesianProduct(inputs.map(inp => Array.isArray(inp) ? inp : enum_to_keys(inp))) as any;

export const cartesian_enum_vals = <T extends EnumOrArray[]>(...inputs: T): { [I in keyof T]: ConvertEnumOrArrayToElement<T[I]> }[] => generateCartesianProduct(inputs.map(inp => Array.isArray(inp) ? inp : enum_to_values(inp))) as any;
```